# Javascript functions aren't working together in MVC Entity Framework

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to work on a view which has a Modal and inside the model, there is a textbox.

What i am trying to do is, when i enter value inside the textbox, it should check and compare if thew entered number is greater/smaller than a value from the database (function check()) AND simultanously trying to restrict the number of textbox inputs to 3 times(function CountClicks()).

I am using ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework in Visual Studio.

**Javascript function check() is not working but countClicks() works**

My Controller code:

```
public ActionResult Sample()
{
    return View(g.Sample_bargain.ToList());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Sample(FormCollection f)
{

     Sample_bargain s = new Sample_bargain();
     var cs = from d in g.Sample_bargain
              where s.Prod_ID == 20
              select s.Bargain_amt;
     ViewBag.bargain = cs;           
     int Bargain = Convert.ToInt32(f["bargain"]);
     return RedirectToAction("Cart");
}
```

My View code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ClickCount = 0;
    function countClicks() {
        var clickLimit = 3; //Max number of clicks
        if (ClickCount >= clickLimit) {
            alert("You can only click this button " + clickLimit + " times.");
            return false;
        }
        else {                                                                                                    
            ClickCount++;
            return true;
        }
    }

    function check() {
        var bargtextbox = document.getElementById("userbarg").value;
        if (@ViewBag.bargain > bargtextbox) {
            alert("Amount too low. Try a better bargain.");
        }
        else {
            alert("Amount High");
        }
    }       
</script>
<input type="number" value="0" id="userbarg" class="abc" name="userbarg" />
<button type="button" class="barg" value="" name="clickOnce" onclick="check(); countClicks(); "> SUBMIT </button>
```

Comment: where is your `click()` function?

Comment: countClick() is inside the view. The first function on top of the check() function

Comment: Are you want to say `check()` is not working? Can you check value inside `ViewBag.bargain` and what is `userbarg`?

Comment: Yes, check() is not working. Even countClick() works only if not assigned alongside with the function check(). userbarg is the id of the textbox of whose value i want to compare with the value from a table in the database

Comment: Try with `ViewBag.bargain = cs.FirstOrDefault();`. And view code you have shared is of `Cart` or `Sample`?

Answer (score 0):

If yor ever open devtool of your browser, F12 on chrome for example, I bet you will see some javascript error.

According your controller code, ViewBag.bargain is located in the POST action, but you will never get to post something back to sever since ViewBag.bargain hasn't been assigned anything yet.

Try move the first five lines of POST action Sample() to the GET one (the one without http method attribute), so your javascript generate no error.